# Lilypond tablature: how to force a note to a specific string+fret?

Tags: guitar, notation, lilypond, tablature

I have written a partition on Lilypond, with both `Staff` and `tabStaff`. I have customised the tablature with `TabStaff.minimumFret = #7` and `TabStaff.restrainOpenStrings = ##t` and the generated tablature is mostly good but I want to change where some notes are placed.

Example, I have the following and want to change this B note to be on the 2nd string on fret 12 (because it makes more sense with the previous bar)

[image]

Is it possible to change one specific note to be assigned to a specific string and fret? Or all the same notes in all the partition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with `\1`, `\2` etc. This is normally used for showing string numbers (so for instance `e'\2` would show a circled 2 near the note to indicate that it should be played on the second string) but it can also be used for moving notes in tab.

In your case, just use something like `b'4\2` instead of the usual `b'4` and the tab should be just like you want it.

There's just one problem with this: the circled 2 will still appear in the top staff with standard notation. If you want to make it go away, just use `\once\omit StringNumber` to get rid of a single number, or `\omit StringNumber` to get rid of all of them. (You can revert that later with `\undo\omit StringNumber` if you need to.)

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I need! Any way to assign b'4 to string 2 in all the partition by default?

Comment: @daks: Alas, I don't know how that could be done, except for using the find&replace facility of your text editor...